What effects would the instant release of large amounts of light have on the air?
I have a character that can store all of the sunlight that hits 1 square meter as a physical material and control the rate of releasing said light.
If she were to instantly release about 1 megajoule of stored sunlight from a source the size of a golfball, what would the effects be on the air?
I know it would produce a lot of heat and probably melt or ignite anything close to it, but would it have any meaningful effects on the air itself? Is this enough energy to ignite the air and cause some sort of an explosion?

Do you mean $1 MJ$? Watts are not a unit of energy.

“produce a lot of heat and probably melt or ignite anything close to it” - that is an explosion. “Ignit[ing] the air” doesn’t mean anything unless you’re talking about a very particular nuclear-physics process that has been shown not to ever happen.

It might lighten it, I suppose.

You're going to need a bigger light bomb. 1MJ of energy is roughly equivalent to 0.11 kg of TNT. And sun-light is so good at passing through the atmosphere without affecting it. Shine a small green laser in a room and you can see it much much better if the room is smoke filled (we conducted this experiment by accident one Thanksgiving).

EDIT: This was written before the OP changed the question to say 1Mj. However, note my comparison to the sunlight absorbed at the equator on the longest day of the year, below.

Next to nothing
Your super hero will get the tan of his/her life, you'll blind everyone (eyes closed or not) within about a thousand feet, you'll tell the aliens in orbit we're ready for a higher form of war... and you'll get a pinch of local atmospheric heating.
Most of the heat you feel during the summer is due to the sunlight hitting you and the ground, not the atmosphere. The atmosphere itself is a distant third when it comes to the heating effects of light.
Why? Because when you get down to looking at the infinitesimally small object that is a photon of light and the comparatively vast distances between molecules that comprise the atmosphere, most of the light won't be absorbed by the atmosphere.
And for the record, let's convert watts to joules: $E(j) = P(w) * t$ and an instant release is, what, a hundredth of a second? So 1E6 * 1/100 = 10,000 joules. Hold this thought.
You sure it wouldn't ignite the atmosphere or something?
Yup. The biggest nuke ever detonated on Earth was the Tsar Bomba. Approximately 50 Mt of explosion resulting in a release of approximately 220 petajoules (which you're nowhere near) of energy that didn't bring to pass the apocalyptic fears of many of the early nuclear bomb scientists. Might have made JFK wet his pants a bit, though. But it just spurred the U.S. to build bigger bombs, assuring MAD, but we're still here so everything's all right no matter what the atomic scientists say, right?
So... a little local atmospheric heating. Depending on the date and location you might not even notice it happened.
Really, not even a little bit?
Nope. Oh, people will be blinded. But you need to realize that all those joules aren't focused on a single small point in space. It's an expanding shell of photons that one second later has either hit the ground or left the atmosphere for open space. Only that portion of the shell that happens to encounter, for example, you, will affect you. That's an issue of your size and distance from the proverbial golf ball... but unless you're standing next to the super hero, you're not even likely to get a tan.
That energy sounds like a lot until you bring physics into it. The reason sunlight is a big deal is because it's not a simple expanding shell of photons... it's a never-ending river of photons. So, while on average (depending on a ridiculous number of variables) an average square meter of ground is getting 100 watts of sunlight, that's 100 joules per-second for the length of the day. At the equator on the longest day of the year (43,665 seconds) that's 4,366,500 joules. A lot more than your burst.
And your burst is just that... a burst. And once the shell has passed in a whole lot less than a fraction of a second, everything goes back to normal.
Which is why @gs is worried about the units you're using. A megawatt assumes a continuous stream of energy that doesn't exist in your scenario.
BTW, if superheros/villains ever did grace the Earth, I would expect those atomic scientists to set the doomsday clock to a millisecond to midnight. I'm just sayin'.

EDIT: With the OP's change to 1Mj it's worth noting that while there still wouldn't be a significant atmospheric change, the absorption of 3 hours worth of sunbathing all at once (if you're standing close enough, like within ten feet of the superhero) would be likely to burn rather than tan — and there'd be a very high chance of melanoma later in life. But other than a very high likelihood of blindness, the moment wouldn't be life threatening. Even the ground wouldn't heat up that much. The truth is, emitting a single burst of light strong enough to super heat the air around the superhero would have environmentally devastating consequences, like setting every building within line of sight for a good quarter mile (at least) on fire and melting most of the metal within a a thousand feet along line of sight and causing every car gasoline tank (and battery!) to explode. Plants, trees, animals and people would be burned to a crisp — but likely still alive (remember, just a shell of photons!). There had better be a whomping good reason lest the local government come knocking with a repair invoice followed by a line of ambulance-chasing attorneys.
If your goal is realism, then realistically your supers would avoid using Weapons of Mass Destruction (area of affect) powers in all but the most dire circumstances. It doesn't matter that you saved the world from certain doom if people can't afford to replace the car that was destroyed in the process because acts-of-superhero-combat insurance is too high. Since that instantly tells supervillains that there's an exploitable weakness (one that's exploited by terrorists today) it would lead to (a) supervillains getting executed rather than placed in a specially-designed jail (call it a penalty enhancement for putting the economy at risk) and (b) the doomsday clock being set to a picosecond from midnight and (c) every scientist on Earth looking for ways to permanently rid the world of all super-anythings. People get really pissed off when they can't afford the collateral damage.
There's a reason I'm not a fan of as-realistic-as-possible.

Basically the answer I was writing. May be able to ignite a small volume of air inside / just around the golfball volume into a very short lived, high-absorption plasma for a little bit of a bang if the superhero gets to alter the spectrum to get more ionizing radiation, though.

Oh, also OP edited to say 1 MJ while you were typing this answer. I think that's fair play since the answer hadn't been posted yet - You may wish to modify a few details of your answer to account for the change.

Still negligible. Absorbance of air is almost exactly zero over distances of centimeters.

@gs Even if it could ignite the air to any degree, it would have no more effect than a small store-bought firework. Now that's my kind of superhero. "You're not going anywhere Dr. Evil!..." pop...

While I sincerely appreciate the coveted green check mark, we ask that you wait 24-48 hours as we have users around the world and human nature is to stop looking at questions that have an accepted answer. You might miss out getting more information and better answers.

Might it get uncomfortably hot near where the release was... through the floor below it absorbing a large-ish part of the light, heating up, and then heating the air near it? Or would we require absurd amounts of sunlight for that?

@Syndic Not due to the atmosphere or atmospheric heating. It would get very hot for a fraction of a second as the photon shell passes by and you absorb your share. That's what I was talking about when I said the superhero would get a tan and that people would get a sunburn. think of it this way: the photon shell is only a photon thick, the speed of light is 299,792 km/s and Earth's atmosphere is only 100 km thick. So the light has left the Earth in 0.0003 s. Long before anyone could react to the light, the wind has blown along what heating might occur.

@Syndic One more thing: Assuming an air molecule is hit by any photons, it's only going to be hit by a small number compared to the whole shell that's expanding as a sphere. The entirety of that photon shell is 1 Mj. But any particular molecule might only be hit by 1-10 joules worth of energy. It really isn't that much. Compare this to the Tsar Bomba that released hundreds of petajoules. Now you're talking about a molecule being hit by thousands to tens of thousands of joules. And the atmosphere still didn't burn. That 1 Mj number really isn't impressive, hence the Austin Powers video link.

@JBH what I meant is: assuming the light is released near the ground, a significant part of it will strike the ground close to the release, and (I assume) heat up that dirt/asphalt/rock. Said heated material would then release heat into the air above it - but I don't have a grasp on how much energy would strike the ground in a radius of 1m, 2m, ... below a release in... 1.5m height or whatever, and how much of it would actually get absorbed rather than reflected as light into the transparent air again? So I hoped you could comment on that

@Syndic If we assume a flat plane, no more than 50% of the light will ever hit the ground. If we assume mountains, buildings, plants and other structures, then more than 50% will hit something not atmosphere. let's assume the worst case and we put the light in a concrete box such that 100% of the burst hits something reasonably local (oh, let's say a meter cubed). What would happen? Next to nothing. The inner surface of the concrete would heat up a bit, and the contained atmosphere might a bit, but that's it. Consider the definitional equation ... (*Continued*)

... for the joule. J = (kg * m)/s^2. Let's assume we're moving a single kg just one meter. We only have a single MJ so time = 1,000 seconds. Except it's a burst! Let's say the burst took only one microsecond (10^-6) and leave the one meter requirement. Now the mass maxes out at 10mg. That's the problem, just a shell of photons one photon thick. Not enough energy to cause much of anything but a sunburn... which doesn't cause local atmospheric heating. Remember, this single MJ burst is 10^-11 the size of the Tsar Bomba and it's open-air, not enclosed. Set expectations appropriately.
